# How can you load defaultor clear a css property from a preceding file (Bootstrap) in another css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say you want to include a third party css stylesheet, but it comes with a property you don't like and it would be great to clear the value that was set.  For example, in [Boostrap.css](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html), you have:

```
select {
  /* how can you clear the below property? */
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

You want selects to not fit the whole width, but scale to the default width (width of text).

Whats the cleanest way to essentially reset the width property to its default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reset the width to `auto` after the 3rd party stylesheet, overwriting the previous property

```
select {
    width: auto;
}
```